# Is a call needed to Setup a method on Mock object that we want to Verify that it is called using Moq?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a unit test that should Verify that a specific method is called when calling *sut.ProcessCommand*.

Is there any benefit of Setting up that method even though I Verify that it is called in my unit test. And that method to be verified doesn't return any value and it is the last method to be called in **MethodA**

Unit Test with Setting up the method

```
 [TestMethod]
 Public void VerifyMethodACalled()
 { 
   Mock<ISomeInterfacce> mockObject=new Mock<ISomeInterface>();
   mockObject.Setup(mockObj=> mockObj.MethodA(It.Is<ClassA>(classAObj=>classAObj.Name="SomeName")));

   //Act
   sut.ProcessCommand();

   mockObject.Verify(mockObj=> mockObj.MethodA(It.Is<ClassA>(classAObj=>classAObj.Name="SomeName")), Times.Once);

 }
```

Unit Test without Setting up the method

```
 [TestMethod]
 Public void VerifyMethodACalled()
 { 
   Mock<ISomeInterfacce> mockObject=new Mock<ISomeInterface>();

   //Act
   sut.ProcessCommand();

   mockObject.Verify(mockObj=> mockObj.MethodA(It.Is<ClassA>(classAObj=>classAObj.Name="SomeName")), Times.Once);

 }
```

Comment: If you are only verifying that call happened then no, a separate setup not needed. Your 2nd test looks good to me

Comment: As an option, you can `Verifiable()` after `Setup()` in first option. If there is no setup needed for mock, second option will be fine

Comment: While not shown in the provided examples the assumption is that the mock is injected into the SUT.

Comment: Perhaps you want to activate the callbase property of the mock?
mockObject.CallBase = true;

Comment: @Rahul That sounds good, after a couple of tries and debugging, it seems that there is no need to setup while the unit test is about verifying the same method.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Yep, The second option makes more sense after a couple of tries I did.

Comment: @Nkosi yes, the mocked dependency is already injected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example, you provided there is absolutely no difference since you verify the method against the invocation list in both cases.

---

Effectively **`moq`** internally maintains the list of setup methods and the list of the invocations. You could verify the method against the invocation list but you can also verify the setup itself. What does that mean? You can think of that verifying against the invocation list, the example you provided, is actually some kind of deferred verification. Let's look at the example (maybe it is not realistic but depicts what I am trying to explain)

```
public class MyData
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IMyInterface
{
    int MyMethod(MyData data);
}
```

**Verify against the invocation list**

```
var p = new Mock<IMyInterface>();
var myData = new MyData {Id = "1"};
p.Object.MyMethod(myData);
myData.Id = "2";
p.Verify(m => m.MyMethod(It.Is<MyData>(d => d.Id == "1"))); //this will fail
```

**Verify against the setup**

```
var p = new Mock<IMyInterface>();
p.Setup(m => m.MyMethod(It.Is<MyData>(d => d.Id == "1"))).Verifiable();
var myData = new MyData {Id = "1"};
p.Object.MyMethod(myData);
myData.Id = "2";
p.Verify(); //this won't fail
```

Comment: Thanks @Johnny for you answer, my question is simpler than what you added, but your answer was an additional information to me that I didn't have an idea about before.